# Complexation of hydroxy chalcone oxime with metal

Tags: organometallic-compounds

Does the complexation of 2-hydroxy chalcone oxime (below) with a metal require any catalyst? Is the complexation pH sensitive?

[image]

Comment: Like what catalyst?

Comment: Here Hydroxy is ortho to oxime so that it can form six membered chelated ring..and catalyst like any acid to deprotonate hydroxy proton ?

Comment: @user46820 maybe if the hydroxyl was on the other ring, but not in the structure shown

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the use of acid/alkali to change the protonation state of a ligand to allow it to complex is generally not considered catalysis.